# How to properly read dimensions for a 3D printer?

Tags: diy-3d-printer, printer-building, desktop-printer

I'm trying to find the correct way to read and understand the dimensions of a 3D printer.  For example, if I read the following dimensions for the [Robo 3D R1 Plus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018E9T50Y) as 10x9x8 Inch - I want to know what **10** stands for (does it mean print height?), **9** (depth?), and **8** (width?); etc.  I'm not sure if I'm assuming correctly.

I know this should be simple, but I'm not sure where to reference the proper ordering, respective to each aforementioned dimension.

**UPDATE**

While looking at [Makerbot's Replicator](https://www.makerbot.com/replicator/) technical specifications, I see them listing their dimensions as follows:

**Build Volume**

```
29.5 L X 19.5 W X 16.5 H CM
[11.6 X 7.6 X 6.5 IN]
```

So, if I'm reading this correctly, can I infer that 11.6 IN is referring to the length/depth, 7.6 IN is referring to the width, and 6.5 IN is referring to the height.  Would this be the universal/standard way of referring to build specifications for all 3D printers?

Comment: LWH is a very common order for measurements, but it's not specific to 3D printing at all.

Comment: Typically LWH is transferable to XYZ dimensions in machine tools (3D Printers, Mills, Lathes, Lasers, etc). ie Length=X Distance, Width=Y Distance, Z=Height.

Comment: The 11.6 value, as L, would be the x direction typically, and therefore the left to right as you are facing the machine.  W would be the front to back "depth" or y dimension.  Your notation of "length/depth" is problematic, I think.

Comment: Just a thought, that it mostly matters to distinguish the Height particularly. Length and Width are somewhat symmetrical - you can re-orientate the print by 90 degrees with little consequence; you usually cannot do that vertically, and it makes a huge difference to the structure of a print if you do. If your printer has a moving bed, the non-symmetry of X and Y might make more of a difference (I don't own a moving-bed printer: does that actually make a difference to your X/Y positioning choices?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the dimensions of your 3D printer ordered in Length x Width x Height is a common way, but nobody actually decided it.
I think it has something to do with the 3rd dimension being the "new" dimension for printing things, that's why it's appended at the end.
Additionally, the first axis on a 2D-coordinate system usually is the horizontal one, so writing Length x Width makes sense for me.
If you are unsure you can always test your printer (if you have one) by writing your own G-Code that moves the printhead on a defined axis.